# Error encountered in upgrading ElasticSearch from version 0.90.5 to version 1.3.2

Tags: java, compilation, elasticsearch, dropbox

I have encountered the following problem in my application in upgrading ElasticSearch from version 0.90.5 to version 1.3.2. Other posts tell that this is a compiler bug.

We are currently using JDK 1.5 to do compilation. I have tried in both JDK 6 and 7 and the error still persists.

Please feel free to let me know if anyone has encountered the same problem and how it was resolved.

Best regards.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.app.work.search.es.EsContextListener
java.lang.VerifyError: class fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river.dropbox.rest.DropboxHelpAction overrides final method handleRequest.(Lorg/elasticsearch/rest/RestRequest;Lor
g/elasticsearch/rest/RestChannel;)V
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river.dropbox.plugin.DropboxRiverPlugin.processModule(DropboxRiverPlugin.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.processModule(PluginsService.java:192)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsModule.processModule(PluginsModule.java:61)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Modules.processModules(Modules.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:192)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166)
```

Comment: Looks like your Dropbox plugin needs to be updated to match the new version of es. Es is notorious for lack of backwards compatibility

Comment: coffeeaddict is right but unfortunately David Pilato still didn't update his [river project](https://github.com/dadoonet/dropbox#versions).